# Find in subdocuments returning document

Tags: mongodb, find

I have a collection looking somewhat like this:

```
{
  "colors": ["blue","white"],
  "items": {
    "old": {
      "name": "test"
    }
    "current": {
      "name": "new_test"
    }
  }
},
{
  "colors": ["red","green"],
  "items": {
    "old": {
      "name": "test2"
    }
    "current": {
      "name": "new_test2"
    }
  }
},
```

Is it possible to use find like this:

```
db.collection.find({"items": { "old": { "name": "test" } } })
```

So the command would return:

```
{
  "colors": ["blue","white"],
  "items": {
    "old": {
      "name": "test"
    }
    "current": {
      "name": "new_test"
    }
  }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the '[dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)' to reach into the object:

```
db.collection.find({"items.old.name": "test" })
```

The query syntax you used also works, but it has different semantics: It will match the *entire subdocument* for equality instead of just a single field. For instance, the following query would also return a result:

```
db.foo.find({"items.old": {"name" : "test"} }),
```

but`db.collection.find({"items": { "old": { "name": "test" } } })` does not, because `items` *also* contains a `current` field.