# MongoDB - $addToSet on a list of Embedded Document

Tags: mongodb, operation, embedded-documents

I have a list of (mongodb) Embedded Documents within one Document and I am interested in adding a new embedded document to the list of the existing ones.

As far as I have researched, I can use $addToSet, what I can't figure out is how does MongoDB decide if the new document already exists in the list of embedded documents or if it's a new one, i.e. how does MongoDB decide if 2 embedded documents are equal?

p.s. the embedded documents I have are not just values, they are quite complex structures, so I was wondering if there is any place I can define what the equality between 2 of them means...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$addToSet` uses the usual [mongodb equality rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605677/find-in-subdocuments-returning-document/19606141#19606141): it will do a deep value-by-value comparison, so the following two documents are identical:

```
{ name: "John", hobbies: ["coding", "drinking", "chess"] }
{ hobbies: ["coding", "drinking", "chess"], name: "John" }
```

(order within documents [is not guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576823/can-mongodb-and-its-drivers-preserve-the-ordering-of-document-elements), so they are identical)

while those aren't (pairwise):

```
// compare to:
{ name: "John", hobbies: ["chess", "coding", "drinking"] } 

// in arrays, the order matters:
{ name: "John", hobbies: ["coding", "drinking", "chess"] } 

// field names and values are case sensitive
{ Name: "John", hobbies: ["chess", "coding", "drinking"] } 
{ name: "john", hobbies: ["chess", "coding", "drinking"] } 

// additional field:
{ name: "John", lastName: "Doe", hobbies: ["chess", "coding", "drinking"] }

// missing field:
{ name: "John" }
```

Please note that there is no special field here. You can add an `_id` field, but it has no special semantics and will be treated just like any other field.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comprehensive answer! I see! It sounds more like a dictionary comparison...

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#value-to-add-is-a-document) the fields order matters, though. Did something change or am I misunderstanding something?