# Adding objecct into an array if object field is unique in MondoDB/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my Schema:

```
let userSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    books: [{ cover: String, title: String, link: String }],
});
```

I am pushing an object to the books array, only if that object does not already exist. I don't understand why this does not work: I am saying find the user, check the `books` array to ensure that title does not exist add the new object to books array. However duplicates still show up in my array.

**note**: The query is being executed inside a function which is passed `model`, `user`, and an object containing the book data called `info` hence the `info.title`.

```
model.findOneAndUpdate(
    { email: user.email, 'books.title': { $ne: 'info.title  ' } },
    { $addToSet: { "books": { title: info.title, cover: 
    info.cover, link: info.link } } },
    { new: true },
    (err, user) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(user);
        }
    )
```

Appreciate the direction

Answer (score 2):

From MongoDB $addToSet documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#behavior

> If the value is a document, MongoDB determines that the document is a
>   duplicate if an existing document in the array matches the to-be-added
>   document exactly; i.e. the existing document has the exact same fields
>   and values and the fields are in the same order. As such, field order
>   matters and you cannot specify that MongoDB compare only a subset of
>   the fields in the document to determine whether the document is a
>   duplicate of an existing array element.

You can also find a good answer here [MongoDB - $addToSet on a list of Embedded Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576282/mongodb-addtoset-on-a-list-of-embedded-document)